# Is it possible to split the file contents using a custom pattern?

Tags: php, regex, parsing, file-get-contents

Is it possible to split the contents of file into parts that have specific pattern?

This is what I want to achieve:

- Read the file using file_get_contents
- Read only contents between similar commented areas.

I am not sure how complicated is that but basically If I am parsing a large html file and want only to display to the browser the specific widgets (pattern is the comment boundaries) like this:

Sample:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
 this content should not be parsed.. ignored
 <!-- widget -->
 this is the widget. i want to parse this content only from the file
 <!-- widget -->
</body>
</html>
```

would it be possible using php and regex or anything to parse the contents between  boundaries only?

I apologize but I tried to explain what I want to achieve as much as I can. hope someone helps me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's certainly possible, but it doesn't really need to be done with regex. I'd probably just do something like this:

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://example.com/');
$widgets = explode('<!-- widget -->', $file);
```

Now the odd elements of `$widget` (`[1], [3], [5]`, etc) contain what was between those boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want with a regular expression (or if you are only ever splitting on  you can probably just use that).  Check the documentation.  The other answer using explode() will probably also work.

```
$text = file_get_contents('/path/to/your/file');
$array = split('<!-- widget -->', $text);
```

The first entry will be everything before the first occurrence of `<!-- widget -->` and the last element will be everything after the last `<!-- widget -->`.  Every odd-numbered element will be what you're looking for.

[Php split function documentation](https://www.php.net/split)

Comment: Very very nice. Quick question..is there any practical difference between explode and split?

Comment: Not really, other than split() supports regular expressions while explode does not.  Honestly, if you're not going to use a regular expression, you should probably use explode() as it is likely faster (has to do with php core loading the regular-expression related stuff for split but not explode).

Comment: Ok thanks for the explaination.. yes i will try to avoid regex since its doable with explode no need to make things complicated.

Answer (score 1):

```
$pattern = "/<!-- widget -->([\s\S]+)<!-- widget -->/";
$match = preg_match_all($pattern,$string,$match_array);

var_dump($match_array);
```